# debugging an array while creating custom rule

Tags: 7, rules, debugging

I am trying debug a custom rule I am creating. In my helper function I am calling an array I want to work with. I want to dpm the contents of the array so that I can see what is available, but it is not working. To check that there wasn't a problem with my array. I set up a new one inside the helper function.

```
$array = [
      "foo" => "bar",
      "bar" => "foo",
  ];
```

and then try to dpm the array:

```
dpm ("array: " . $array);
```

but all that is shown in the status message is:

```
array: Array
```

I have been trying other methods of printing the array like print_r but haven't had any success with these either. How should I be printing my array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have a *string* (not an array) as the second argument to `dpm()`.

Try:

```
dpm($array, "array: ");
```

Comment: Thanks. I had been banging my head against the wall over that!

Comment: I would advise using xdebug to debug this sort of thing - it will really save you the headache of trying to debug custom rules.